# How to use Postgres and static file manupulation in Nginx

Tags: postgresql, nginx

I would like to use Nginx as my CDN for a file hosting system. I saw a great module for nginx that allows postgres connection (https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres) it works really well, however when I try to use it while having alias directive it seems to ignore the alias or file download and rather give me an empty file.
My idea is, to use the UUID from the URL and find the correct file doing a query and then using the found details to change the filename header so that the user's client will download automatically set the name to the original filename instead of a uuid.

Here is the code.

```
    location /dl{
        postgres_output none;
        postgres_pass   database;
        postgres_query  "SELECT * FROM \"Files\" WHERE uuid = '$args'";
        postgres_set $filename 0 name;



        alias /home/ubuntu/fileStorage;
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$filename";

    }
```

I think somehow the postgres directive is locking up this block. Is there a way I can run the postgres query without effecting the download block?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you expect that the line

```
add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$filename";
```

will cause the browser to download the file given by `$filename`. This is not how the Content-Disposition header works, it simply tells the browser to interpret the response body as a file. You're going to have to do something additional to get the proper content to the client. Perhaps what you really want is to issue a redirect?

Comment: Im not sure about the redirect. If my url is dl.domain.com/111-222-333/, then the rule block should fetch the file info based on 111-222-333 and redirect to dl.domain.com/humanReadableFileName.zip? Wouldn't that mean the file is also accessible if the user directly went to the redirected Url in the first place? thus having 2 ways of getting the file.

Comment: Yes there would be 2 ways of getting a file but this would be true in the example you posted anyway. You could use `rewrite` but I don't know if you can have a variable on the left side of a rewrite directive. Another option might be to proxy to a second instance of nginx running on a different port, with its root set to `/home/ubuntu/fileStorage;`.